# JQuery: Unable scroll to bottom of page when using addClass & removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

I have the following code that is adding the class "sticky" on scroll and removing the class "sticky" when the element reaches the anchor "#search-anchor".

However, I'm unable to scroll all the way down to see the full footer. Any ideas why?

https://jsfiddle.net/coldfusion/6z6q3kxm/2/

```
<style>
header,footer {height:50px;background-color:red;}
section {height: 50px; background-color: yellow;}
#search-anchor {background-color:blue;}
.body {height:1600px;background-color:black;}
.sticky {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0px;
   width: 1000px;
   margin-right: auto !important;
   margin-left: auto !important;
   z-index: 999;
}
</style>

<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var a = jQuery(".inline-search").offset().top,
        n = function() {
            var n = jQuery(window).scrollTop(),
                n = n + 10;
            n > a ? jQuery(".inline-search").addClass("sticky") : jQuery(".inline-search").removeClass("sticky")
        };
    n(), jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        n()
    })
}),

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var search = $(".inline-search");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var anchorPosition = $("#search-anchor").offset().top;
        var navHeight = $(".inline-search").height();
        var navPosition = $(".inline-search").offset().top;

        if ((navPosition + navHeight) >= anchorPosition) {
            search.removeClass('sticky');
        }

    })
});

</script>

<header>HEADER</header>
<section class="inline-search">
</section>
<div class="body"></div>
<section id="search-anchor">
</section>
<footer>FOOTER</footer>
```

Comment: why use 2 ready function ?

Comment: you can scroll all the way down, however your footer has a 50px height which makes it tiny

Comment: @denisol - You can adjust the height of the footer and you will still not be able to scroll down to the bottom. Look at the scroll bar on the right side. You cannot get it to the bottom.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Comment: It's likely because you're changing the `position` of the `.inline-search` to `fixed`, which pulls it out of the flow, decreasing the height. When you scroll down to the "bottom" you remove that `position`, reintroducing it into the flow and increasing the height. For some reason, the browser is not updating the scrollbar to allow for that change.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - Added code. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the instruction `debugger` to pause the execution of JavaScript in the console, you get exactly what @mike-mccaughan is explaining.

You script adds and removes the element `.inline-search`from the document flow because of the CSS `position:fixed;`.

If you scroll down and re-add `.inline-search` to the document flow, the document height changes again and the scrollbar has some space, so your code that detects if we're at the bottom of the page doesn't work anymore. What happens is an infinite and very fast loop of adding and re-adding your fixed positioning: because of that, it seems as if the page "stops" scrolling before getting to the footer.

In order to create such an effect (fixed positioning upon scroll), I'd recommend using Bootstrap's affix jQuery plugin. Even further: Bootstrap recently announced that they're dropping Affix because of sticky positioning coming to CSS, so the real "future-proof" recommendation here would be to use sticky positioning with a polyfill to allow older browsers to have the same effect.

- Bootstrap affix : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/affix.js,
  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix
- Bootstrap drops affix : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/87751da48232ac4ca1964c819aaf89e78a3f9e64/docs/migration.md
- Sticky positioning : http://html5please.com/#sticky
- Sticky positioning demo : http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/sticky.html  - Sticky positioning availability accross browsers : http://caniuse.com/#feat=css sticky
- And a sticky positioning polyfill for older browsers : https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-sticky